# Sugurim maps are not working with ASP.NET wizard

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps, subgurim-maps

When I put the subgurim map into the asp.net wizards second step then getting error as below.

Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

If anybody can help then very appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when upgrading and using the map in a user control. I had to manually add   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">`
     into the user control and it now works fine